# Bypass password protected posts via GET variable

Tags: password

I like to bypass the password form of protected posts with a GET variable with following requirements:

- No changes to the core
- No clear exposure of the password (hashing)
- No security leaks

**No changes to the core**

This is a no brainer as the functionality should be in a plugin and working out of the box. I [found](http://www.kieranlane.com/2011/12/15/bypass-a-wordpress-password-protected-post-or-page-via-a-url/) some [methods](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/bypass-password-prompt-with-direct-link-to-protected-page) which changes the core file.

**No clear exposure of the password**

Instead of `http://example.com/post?pwd=mypassword` the URL should be something like `http://example.com/post?pwd=%25P%25BaxfPUloy8YdOFi2F9F2xAcCg8OLGP`

**No possible security leaks**

Of course this should not get "hacked" somehow. They are only protected posts but nevertheless this is a no go.

**What I need:**

A way to get the hash appended to the URL:

```
$url = add_query_arg(array(
    'pwd' => get_my_hash();
), get_permalink($post_id));
```

and on the page template the code:

```
if(post_password_required()){
    if(isset($_GET['pwd'])){
        if(check_pwd_with_hash($_GET['pwd'])){
        //unlock content
        }
    }
}

the_content();
```

There's no way to hook into the [`post_password_required()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L760) method or simple set the global `$post->post_password` to an empty string.

Comment: For future readers, there is a filter hook for this (`post_password_required`) from v4.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The check for a post password happens (for some reason) inside `get_the_content()`, which *seems* legit, but actually mixes together two separate concerns. You were right with the statement that there is no way to work around `get_the_content()` displaying the password form. Here's what the check for the password does in core in detail:

```
if ( empty( $post->post_password ) )
     return false;

if ( ! isset( $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] ) )
     return true;

require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';
$hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );
$hash = wp_unslash( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] );
if ( 0 !== strpos( $hash, '$P$B' ) )
     return true;
return ! $hasher->CheckPassword( $post->post_password, $hash );
```

As you can see, the password gets check against a *Cookie* stored at the users machine.

To circumvent the post password, you will actually have to give the user explicit permission by setting this cookie. Core does it the following way:

```
setcookie(
    'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH,
    $hasher->HashPassword( wp_unslash( $_POST['post_password'] ) ),
    $expire,
    COOKIEPATH
);
```

when you look at [`the_post_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_password/), which is used to retrieve the (plain text password), then you will find that it does nothing aside from escaping the argument for the users safety:

```
esc_attr( $post->post_password )
```

Now you can combine this and set the Cookie *before* you display the content in your template:

```
// Your custom check for the `$_GET` content
// …also check if there in fact is a password
// …and if the user is a repeated visitor, do not set the Cookie again
if (
        isset( $_GET['circumvent'] ) 
        and 'disable-pass' === $_GET['circumvent'] 
        and isset( $post->post_password )
        and ! isset( 'wp-postpass_'.COOKIEHASH )
    ) {
    // Finally we use the plain text password to set the Cookie
    // as if the user would have entered it into the password form
    setcookie(
        'wp-postpass_'.COOKIEHASH,
        $hasher->HashPassword( wp_unslash( esc_attr( $post->post_password ) ) ),
        $expire,
        COOKIEPATH
    );
}
// Now display the content:
the_content();
```

> *Additional [information](http://unserkaiser.com/blog/2014/02/21/wordpress-password-protected-posts-feature-or-security-leak/) about Post Passwords in this article I wrote as much of this concept is known very little and you might want to account for some of those details.*