# Bypass a WordPress Password Protected Post or Page via a URL

Tags: password

I have a password protected page that i would like to be accessible with a custom link with the password as get variable in url
www.domaine.tld/my-page?code=mycustompassword

I have found this but this is not working
[Bypass password protected posts via GET variable](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229811/bypass-password-protected-posts-via-get-variable)

Could you pleaser help me to bypass the password form

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
    add_filter( 'post_password_required', function( $returned, $post )
{
   
    if( $returned && ( $_GET['pwd'] ==  $post->post_password ) )
        $returned = false;
    return $returned;

}, 10, 2 );
```

**Bypass link for password-protected page. Need to add in the theme function file. The link should be look like. `https://www.example.com/post/?pwd=PASSWORD`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same principle as the worked example, however replace `$_GET` with `$_POST`. So you'd have something like this towards the end:

```
// Your custom check for the '$_POST' content
// …also check if there in fact is a password
// …and if the user is a repeated visitor, do not set the Cookie again
if (
        isset( $_POST['circumvent'] ) 
        and 'disable-pass' === $_POST['circumvent'] 
        and isset( $post->post_password )
        and ! isset( 'wp-postpass_'.COOKIEHASH )
    ) {
    // Finally we use the plain text password to set the Cookie
    // as if the user would have entered it into the password form
    setcookie(
        'wp-postpass_'.COOKIEHASH,
        $hasher->HashPassword( wp_unslash( esc_attr( $post->post_password ) ) ),
        $expire,
        COOKIEPATH
    );
}
// Now display the content:
the_content();
```

Comment: Hello thanks fot anwser i got this : PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function HashPassword() on a non-object in /home/test-user/public_html/wp-content/themes/default/template-landing-private.php on line 81

Comment: You may need to add `global $hasher;` at the start. Otherwise can you post the entire file?

Comment: /* Template Name: TEST */

if (
 isset( $_GET['code'] ) 
 and 'mycustompassword' === $_GET['code'] 
 and isset( $post->post_password )
 and null !== 'wp-postpass_'.COOKIEHASH
 //!isset( 'wp-postpass_'.COOKIEHASH )
) {
 setcookie(
  'wp-postpass_'.COOKIEHASH, 
  $hasher->HashPassword( wp_unslash( esc_attr( $post->post_password ) ) ),
  $expire,
  COOKIEPATH
 );
}


get_header();
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 the_content();
endwhile;
get_footer();

Comment: Please post your code between back ticks (\`) so that it's formatted properly

Comment: Hello, sorry i have post an anwser below with the complete code. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the_content(), use echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ); i could be wrong but i believe that this will bypass the password form entirely, then you can do your own simple logic for whether or not to show the content. In either case however i strongly advise not doing this if the content is very sensitive data.  ie. i hope it's not someone's personal information. you will additionally have to make sure the post has a password so that it doesn't show up in search results, sitemaps, feeds, or wp json api endpoints.